# Why can we measure current in AC voltages?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, measurement

From Wikipedia:

> The drift velocity deals with the average velocity of a particle, such as an electron, due to an electric field. In general, an electron will propagate randomly in a conductor at the Fermi velocity.[5] Free electrons in a conductor follow a random path. Without the presence of an electric field, the electrons have no net velocity. When a DC voltage is applied, the electron drift velocity will increase in speed proportionally to the strength of the electric field. The drift velocity is on the order of millimeters per hour. AC voltages cause no net movement; the electrons oscillate back and forth in response to the alternating electric field (over a distance of a few micrometers

This can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_electricity)

If AC voltages are causing no movement how is it that we can measure current, which is defined as - The net rate of flow of electric charge past a region.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: One word: [Root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *What am I missing here?*

> **AC voltages cause no \$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{net}}}\$ movement.**

You might have missed the red word above. It means average i.e. there is no long-term average movement but, of course, there is movement of charge for each half cycle of the applied AC waveform; one in one direction and the other in the reverse direction, averaging to zero.

> *If AC voltages are causing no movement how is it that we can measure
> current*

AC is causing movement but no \$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{net}}}\$ movement.

<sub>Note to Neil: \$\require{cancel} \cancel{cancel}\$ works in answers</sub>

Comment: That's a fun markup, red, boxed. Must use it some time. Where's the full list of these?

Comment: @Neil_UK dunno. I kind of stumbled across it when doing my crappy website.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Things are never this easy are they?

Comment: @ZhelyazkoGrudov you'll get used to it!!

Comment: @Andyaka After a little searching, I've saved a file for myself with these links, [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) [markdown 1](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) [markdown 2](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/)

Comment: @Neil_UK Which one has the \$\boxed{\text{boxed}}\$ reference? I scanned 'em but maybe missed it?

Comment: @Neil_UK found it plus this useful "strikeout" \$\require{canel} \cancel{feature}\$ : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/13183#13183 - oh maybe it doesn't work in comments d'oh.

Comment: Aha it works in comments providing you have used it in the question (which I have).

Comment: @Andyaka Mathjax, but it's way down the long page, under 'decorations', another useful feature is markdown ~~strikes out~~ with two tildes each side, rather than using the html-like strike \strike (but maybe not in comments!)(not even in answers, bum steer)

Comment: That's nice to know - I didn't know about the ~~tilda~~ thing. Yeah it don't work in comments \$\cancel{\text{bad tilda}}\$ haha.

Answer (score 0):

If the wire was one atom thick, there would be a net migration of electrons in ac and DC, but the problem is scale.

1A is \$6.24 \times 10^{18}\$ electrons flowing in one second.  That's a lot of electrons and as far as we are concerned, infinite.

But to allow those electrons to flow, looking at the cross sectional area of a wire, there must be significantly more copper atoms.

Copper has 29 electrons arranged in electron levels as: 2, 8, 18 and 1.  That 1 electron in the valence shell accounts for the good conduction of copper.  It is far (in atomic terms) from the nucleus and held by 1 proton.  It can become a free electron with the application of little energy (heat, light, emf).  The copper atom becomes a copper ion \$Cu^+\$, which will attract a free electron.  The flow of electrons from atom to atom is current (net flow of electrons).

So individual electrons might only flow m, the net flow is what matters.  To get 1A of current to flow, \$6.24 \times 10^{18}\$ electrons must flow through the cross-sectional area of the wire in one second.